# Writing shorter datatypes to memory doesn't affect runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, int, benchmarking

I've been comparing the write times for several datatypes, and I've noticed something I find highly baffling. Firstly, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>

#define its 1000000
#define len 1000

int main()
{
    std::array<int, len> int_arr;
    std::array<char, len> char_arr;
    std::array<bool, len> bool_arr;
    std::clock_t begin = std::clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < its; ++i)
    {
        std::fill(int_arr.begin(), int_arr.end(), 0);
    }
    std::clock_t end = std::clock();
    double elapsed = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "int_arr " << elapsed << std::endl;
    begin = std::clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < its; ++i)
    {
        std::fill(char_arr.begin(), char_arr.end(), 0);
    }
    end = std::clock();
    elapsed = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "char_arr " << elapsed << std::endl;
    begin = std::clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < its; ++i)
    {
        std::fill(bool_arr.begin(), bool_arr.end(), false);
    }
    end = std::clock();
    elapsed = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "bool_arr " << elapsed << std::endl;
}
```

This code compares the times taken to write to arrays containing different datatypes (the repeated fills are to make the runtimes meaningfully measurable). I would expect `char` and `bool` to take roughly the same amount of time, since the computer still has to write the full byte into RAM. Furthermore, since `int` takes 4 bytes, I would expect it to run four times as slowly.
I compiled the above code with the `-O3` optimizer flag and with `-std=c++11`. Contrary to my expectations, the result varies greatly! As expected, `char` and `bool` take the same amount of time as each other consistently (and also the same amount of time between runs). However, approximately half the time `int` is only twice as slow (in this case, a factor of 2.19):

```
int_arr 0.043705
char_arr 0.01995
bool_arr 0.022835
```

And the other half of the time, it is four times as slow (in this case, a factor of 3.91):

```
int_arr 0.076907
char_arr 0.01965
bool_arr 0.019354
```

Furthermore, it is never in between! What on earth is going on here? An explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I would expect char and bool to take roughly the same amount of time, since the computer still has to write the full byte into RAM. " - have you checked the generated assembly? Have you checked the performance counters that your CPU exposes? I found it best to use Google's [benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) library when microbenchmarking, altogether with `perf` on Linux. You might want to use them too, as they will give you a lot more data.

Comment: Factors: size of data written vs. size of L1, L2, L3 caches;  how large each cache line in each cache is;  how/when each cache is flushed to the next level and finally to RAM.  Some of your data lengths are small enough to fit in my L2 cache.  So each test may end up measuring  the time to flush the previous test and not it's own time.

Comment: While you analyze the generated assembly, you might also want to spend some time reading [Agner Fog's optimization manuals,](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) which will likely help explain what's happening.

Comment: *I compiled the above code with the -O3 optimizer flag* -- Well, thanks for that.  Most of the time, we see questions like this and it becomes a waste of time and effort when it is discovered the poster tested with no optimizations being turned on.